# Spring kafkaTemplate - don't want to reconnect while sending message ( when send is triggered kafka server is down)

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have created kafka producer in spring. While sending message, at start broker/server are turned off. Before timeouts are reached I'm starting kafka server.

```
  kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord).get(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Even then i get excpetion:

**RMI TCP Connection(9)-192.168.201.1: [192.168.201.1] exception:
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication**

At the end I get exception:

**org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic Dummy-Topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.**

Spring kafkaTemplate - don't want to reconnect while sending message ( when send is triggered kafka server is down)

Props of my producer:

```
        final Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
        props.putAll(kafkaProperties.getProducer().buildProperties());
        props.put("ReplyToTopicName","dummyResponseTopic");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 2);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 100);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 50);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,15000);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 20000);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 60000);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
```